# ListBox with embedded CheckBox restricting one item to be checked

Tags: wpf, checkbox, listbox

I have a ListBox containing an ItemTemplate made up of a StackPanel containing a CheckBox and a Label.  I want to allow only one list item to be checked at a time.  I am having trouble understanding how I can get this accomplished.  Here is the XAML describing the listbox:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0"
         Grid.Column="0"
         Width="180"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         x:Name="listboxPlayers"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Players}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPlayer, Mode=TwoWay}"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsDefault, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          Checked="CheckBox_Checked"
                          Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

A Player is defined as this:

```
public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
}
```

My list of `Players` is defined like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<Player> Players { get; private set; }
```

My `SelectedPlayer` is defined like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedPlayerProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedPlayer", typeof(Player), typeof(MainWindow),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());

public Player SelectedPlayer
{
    get { return (Player)GetValue(SelectedPlayerProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedPlayerProperty, value); }
}
```

I haven't been able to find a post or question that can help me.  I've played with using a Checked event handler for the CheckBox but I can't seem to wrap my head around how I can relate the list to the correct `Player` in the list because the ListBox doesn't adjust the `SelectedPlayer` when the CheckBox is checked or unchecked.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have something that should behave like a [`RadioButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton.aspx), why not use a `RadioButton`?

Comment: Can I do it with dynamically added RadioButtons?

Comment: Yes, why not? Just make sure to assign a common `GroupName`.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the following style for displaying a ListBox using CheckBoxes (You can use RadioButtons too by just replacing the `CheckBox` control with a `RadioButton`

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxListBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation" Value="Cycle" />
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" >
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2, 2, 2, 0" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border Background="Transparent">
                                <CheckBox IsHitTestVisible="False" Focusable="false" 
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding ContentPresenter.Content}"  
                                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then it is simply used by something like

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Players}"
         Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxListBoxStyle}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPlayer, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring your ListBox to Selection Mode Single.  And rather than a separate label you could just bind Name to the Content property of the CheckBox.  I like the way that spaces.  And you may need to implement InotifyPropertyChanged on player.